# Scrapy Throwing a "max redirections reached" even though the URL is the same

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, python-requests

For some unusual reason Scrapy keeps throwing "max redirections reached" even though the URL that it says it is redirecting to is the same...

```
In [1]: fetch('http://www.website.com/ap/001/new')
2018-03-16 20:50:06 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-03-16 20:50:06 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:08 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:08 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:08 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:08 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:08 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (meta refresh) to <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new> from <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>
2018-03-16 20:50:08 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Discarding <GET http://www.website.com/ap/001/new>: max redirections reached
```

If I scrape with requests & urllib2 but scrapy it fails... What is going on to cause this & how do I fix it. I can't find anything on stackoverflow/google matching this issue.

I've checked the URL in my browser and on "redirect checkers" and none of them think the site is redirecting so not sure why scrapy thinks it is redirecting.

Comment: They have surely blocked you from scraping, and showing some sort of Captcha

Comment: @Umair Nope. I've tried the website in Firefox using the exact same proxy & exact same user agent and the site works fine.

Comment: Try printing source-code and see whats coming. Also try `meta={'dont_redirect': True,"handle_httpstatus_list": [302]}` in your `Request()`